# Custom struct with output like DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, struct, return

it's difficult to write my Question in the title...
I want to ask how I can create a struct that is like DateTime.
When I print a DateTime variable it returns Day.Month.Year...
Then I create a struct (just an example)

```
struct Test
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
}

class program
{
   static void Main()
   {
      Test customstruct;
      Console.WriteLine(customstruct);
   }
}
```

I want to print(a.b.c)
Of course I could write a string in the output, but if I use a datagrid for example, the struct has to return a.b.c

I hope that I explaine it good enough,
Thankful for any help!

Comment: You need to override the `ToString` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this overriding `ToString()` method:

```
struct Test
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", a, b, c);
    }
}
```